# ¿Como consultar where sqlite con dos campos?

Tags: android, sqlite

Al momento de ingresar mi dato en el Edittext ya sea el codigo (ejemplo "1") o nombre(ejemplo "pepe") solo me lista  cuando  ingreso el codigo, pero cuando ingreso el  nombre no y quiero que me liste por nombre o codigo al momento de hacer la consulta, creo que la consulta sql esta fallando.

```
private void consultarSql() {

    SQLiteDatabase db=cnn.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] parametros={edtcodigo.getText().toString(),edtnombre.getText().toString()};

    try {

        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT "+Utilidades.CAMPO_NOMBRE+","+Utilidades.CAMPO_APELLIDO+
                " FROM "+Utilidades.TABLA_USUARIO+" WHERE "+Utilidades.CAMPO_ID+"= ? or "+Utilidades.CAMPO_NOMBRE+"=?  ",parametros);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        edtnombre.setText(cursor.getString(0));
        edtapellido.setText(cursor.getString(1));


    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"El CODIGO O NOMBRE no existe",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        limpiar();
        db.close();

    }

}
```

Esta es mi clase Utilidades

```
package aplicacion.android.jaramillojade.ejemplologin1.Utilidades;

public class Utilidades {

//CONSTANTES DE LA TABLA

public static final String TABLA_USUARIO= "USUARIO";
public static final String CAMPO_ID= "id";
public static final String CAMPO_NOMBRE= "nombre";
public static final String CAMPO_APELLIDO= "apellido";




public static final String CREAR_TABLA_USUARIO= "CREATE TABLE "+TABLA_USUARIO+" ("+CAMPO_ID+" INTEGER , "+CAMPO_NOMBRE+" TEXT, "+CAMPO_APELLIDO+" TEXT)";

}
```

Comment: tengo una clase Utilidades donde guardo
 public static final String TABLA_USUARIO= "USUARIO";
    public static final String CAMPO_ID= "id";
    public static final String CAMPO_NOMBRE= "nombre";
    public static final String CAMPO_APELLIDO= "apellido";
    public static final String CAMPO_CORREO= "correo";

Comment: Y como se supone que los ordenas? si se muestran ordenados así tal cual lo tienes es porque el id es autoincrementable supongo, osea "ya esta ordenado", pero ahi no veo ninguna sentencia para ordenarlos de A-Z. Hago este comentario porque eso es lo que entiendo yo de tu pregunta.

Comment: el id no es autoincrementable, yo  tengo una clase registrar_usuario el cual tengo ingresado  en mi tabla "usuario" el id, nombre y apellido (1,jose,perez) y tengo otra clase consultar_usuario el cual quiero hacer la consulta por nombre o codigo si encuentra me va listar en dos edittext que tengo.

Answer (score 1):

Agregando dos cursores y condicionales logre hacer la consulta para dos parametros, gracias a todos por su ayuda!!

```
private void consultarSql() {
    SQLiteDatabase db=cnn.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] parametros={edtcodigo.getText().toString()};
    String[] campos={Utilidades.CAMPO_NOMBRE,Utilidades.CAMPO_APELLIDO};
        


Cursor cursor1 =db.query(Utilidades.TABLA_USUARIO,campos,Utilidades.CAMPO_ID +"=?" ,parametros,null,null,null);
        Cursor cursor2 =db.query(Utilidades.TABLA_USUARIO,campos,Utilidades.CAMPO_NOMBRE +"=?" ,parametros,null,null,null);

        try {

            if (cursor1.moveToFirst()){

                edtnombre.setText(cursor1.getString(0));
                edtapellido.setText(cursor1.getString(1));


            }else{
                cursor2.moveToFirst();
                edtnombre.setText(cursor2.getString(0));
                edtapellido.setText(cursor2.getString(1));

            }




        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"El documento no existe",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            limpiar();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola esta es la manera correcta de crear y utilizar una base de datos SQLite en Android.
Debes de utilizar este sistema para evitar inyecciones SQL, o que el usuario desde su dispositivo pueda acceder a la base de datos, e introducir datos falsos:

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL

PASO 1 debes de crear una clase contrato:

```
public class YourAppContract {

    public static final String CONTENT_AUTHORITY = "com.example.yourapp";
    public static final Uri BASE_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY);

    public static final String PATH_USER = "user";
    public static final String PATH_USER_ID = "user_id";
    public static final String PATH_USER_COUNT = "user_count";


    public static final class YourAppEntry implements BaseColumns {
        public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_USER = Uri.withAppendedPath(BASE_CONTENT_URI, PATH_USER);
        public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_USER_ID = Uri.withAppendedPath(BASE_CONTENT_URI, PATH_USER_ID);
        public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_USER_COUNT = Uri.withAppendedPath(BASE_CONTENT_URI, PATH_USER_COUNT);

        public final static String TABLE_USER_NAME = "user";
        public final static String COLUMN_USER_ID = "_id";
        public final static String COLUMN_USER_USER = "user";

    }
}
```

PASO 2 debes de crear la base de datos:

```
    public class YourAppDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

            public static final String LOG_TAG = YourAppDbHelper.class.getSimpleName();
            private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "YourApp.db";
            private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
            private Context context;
            private ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            private SQLiteDatabase db;

            public YourAppDbHelper(Context context) {
                super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
                this.context = context;
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                String SQL_CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + YourAppContract.YourAppEntry.TABLE_USER_NAME + " ("
                        + YourAppContract.YourAppEntry.COLUMN_USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                        + YourAppContract.YourAppEntry.COLUMN_USER_USER + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                        + YourAppContract.YourAppEntry.COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

                db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_USER_TABLE);
            }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
      db.setVersion(newVersion);
  }

}
```

PASO 3 debes crear una clase ContentProvider:

```
    public class YourAppProvider extends ContentProvider {

        public static final int USER = 100;
        public static final int USER_ID = 101;
        public static final int USER_COUNT = 102;

        public static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

        static {
            sUriMatcher.addURI(YourAppContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, YourAppContract.PATH_USER, USER);
            sUriMatcher.addURI(YourAppContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, YourAppContract.PATH_USER_ID, USER_ID);
            sUriMatcher.addURI(YourAppContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, YourAppContract.PATH_USER_COUNT, USER_COUNT);
        }

    public static final String LOG_TAG = YourDbHelper.class.getSimpleName();
    private YourDbHelper yourAppHelper;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        yourAppHelper = new YourAppDbHelper(getContext());
        return false;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Cursor query(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable String[] projection, @Nullable String selection, @Nullable String[] selectionArgs, @Nullable String sortOrder) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = yourAppHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri); 
        String table = null;
        Cursor cursor;
        switch (match) {
           case USER:
            table = YourAppContract.YourAppEntry.TABLE_USER_NAME;
            break;
           case USER_ID:
            table = YourAppContract.YourAppEntry.TABLE_USER_NAME;
            selection = YourAppContract.YourAppEntry.COLUMN_USER_ID + "=?";
            //selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(ContentUris.parseId(uri))};
            break;
            case USER_COUNT:
            cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM user", null);
            cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
            return cursor;
        }
        cursor = db.query(table, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder, null, null);
        cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
        return cursor;
     }
//resto de metodos de content provider UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT...
//.....
    }
```

PASO 4 debes configurar el provider en el archivo AndroidManifest:

```
<provider
            android:name=".database.YourAppProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.yourapp"
            android:exported="false"
            android:permission="permission"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.yourapp.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```

PASO 5 crear consultas personalizadas y utilizar tu Content Provider:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_main);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    String[] projection = {YourAppContract.YourAppEntry.COLUMN_USER_ID, YourAppContract.YourAppEntry.COLUMN_USER_USER};
                    String clause = YourAppContract.YourAppEntry.COLUMN_USER_ID + "=? "+YourAppContract.YourAppEntry.COLUMN_USER_USER+"=? ";
                    String[] values = {"","Pepe"};
                    cursor = getContentResolver().query(YourAppContract.YourAppEntry.CONTENT_URI_USER, projection, clause, values, null);
                    if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
                       //tu codigo
                    } else if(cursor.getCount()==1) {
                      cursor.moveToFirst();
                    } else if(cursor.getCount()>1){
                      //tu codigo
                    }

}
```

Comment: Ya lo agregue pero igual me sigue buscando solo por codigo

Comment: Mirate la respuesta editada

Comment: Es importante que utilizes este sistema ya que sino, si quieres publicar tu App en Google Play, te clasificaran la App como no segura.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void consultarSql() {




        SQLiteDatabase db=cnn.getReadableDatabase();
       // String[] parametros={edtcodigo.getText().toString()};
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT "+Utilidades.CAMPO_NOMBRE+","+Utilidades.CAMPO_APELLIDO+
                " FROM "+Utilidades.TABLA_USUARIO+" WHERE "+Utilidades.CAMPO_ID+"= '"+edtcodigo.getText().toString()+"' OR "+Utilidades.CAMPO_NOMBRE+"='"+edtnombre.getText().toString()+"' ",null);

        try {



            if (cursor.moveToFirst()){

                do {
                    edtnombre.setText(cursor.getString(0));
                    edtapellido.setText(cursor.getString(1));
                }while (cursor.moveToNext()) ;

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"El CODIGO O NOMBRE no existe",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                limpiar();
            }






        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"El CODIGO O NOMBRE no existe",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            limpiar();


        }
        db.close();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Realmente, aunque la consulta encuentre más de un registro, sólo lees el primero, por eso piensas que no busca por nombre.

Cuando pones...

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
edtnombre.setText(cursor.getString(0));
edtapellido.setText(cursor.getString(1));
```

... estás leyendo los datos del primer registro encontrado.

Para leer todos los registros, debes crear un bucle del tipo...

```
cursor.moveToFirst;
do {

    //Hacer lo que necesites con cada registro.

// } while (cursor.read()) -- Se me iba a c#
} while (cursor.moveToNext)
```

Así lees todos los registros que la consulta ha extraído de la base de datos.

Comment: Estoy deacuerdo contigo, ya se lo dije yo tambien que hiciera un while(cursor.moveToNext()){ }

Comment: Esta seria otra solucion: if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
                       //tu codigo
                    } else if(cursor.getCount()==1) {
                      cursor.moveToFirst();
                    } else if(cursor.getCount()>1){
                      //tu codigo
                    }

Comment: Igual agregando el bucle while solo me busca un registro, osea por codigo.

Comment: O tendria que crear dos cursores uno para buscar por codigo y otro para buscar por nombre y luego mostrarlos con la condicionales?

Comment: Con un While, recorres todos los registros del cursor. El problema es lo que hagas con el. Si cada vez que lees un registro lo escribes en un EditText, sólo aparecerá en el mismo el último registro. Si lo que quieres es tener una lista de los registros que coincidan con el Id y con el Nombre, la consulta está bien, pero tienes que meter los resultados en algún sitio, como por ejemplo un ListView. Por otra parte, si lo que quieres es cargar el registro que tenga el Id y el Nombre (que coincidan los dos a la vez), entonces tienes que cambiar el OR por un AND en la consulta.